# WebClient, UseDefaultCredentials, IIS, WindowsAuthentication, and TaskScheduler

Tags: iis, webclient, windows-authentication, windows-task-scheduler

I have written a .NET console app that fetches some values from an intranet web app using  `System.Net.WebClient` with `UseDefaultCredentials = true`. The web app uses Windows Authentication and allows all users logged into the network and denies anonymous users:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>

<authorization>      
  <allow users="*" />    
  <deny users= "?"/>
</authorization>
```

The console app works fine when I run it on my PC by double-clicking on the program's EXE file. It does what it's supposed to do.

However, when the same program is run on the same PC as a scheduled task using TaskScheduler, it cannot establish communication with the intranet web app.

The console app is set to run under a particular user account —my own— the same account I'm using when double-clicking on the program's exe, and it is set to run whether the user is logged in or not. I have also tried with "Run with the highest privileges" enabled and disabled.

When configuring the task, TaskScheduler asks for the run-account password, which I supply. The option to prevent the password from being stored is not checked.

Is the problem here in the context of TaskScheduler that my WebClient subclass is set to use `UseDefaultCredentials = true`?

P.S. I should also add that the program's `Main()` routine is testing for command line arguments and assuming that if they exist, args[1] and args[2] contain particular values it needs and if not, it uses default values.  Does TaskScheduler supply any command line arguments to the executables it launches? I am assuming that it does not do so.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Do you have the exception details?

Comment: It is a `System.ArgumentNullException` when I try to reference a variable that should contain a value that was fetched from the web app. I am going to read up on how to listen for timeout exceptions with .NET Framework `WebClient`.

Comment: But I suspect it has something to do with Windows Authentication.

Comment: Are you running the intranet web app in IIS? If so, it is recommended that you enable fail request tracing to check whether the authentication is successful when the console app establishes a connection, and whether the intranet web app gives a response to the console app.

Comment: @Bruce Zhang: yes, in IIS.  At the moment, Remote Desktop Connection is returning an "internal error" and I'm unable to access IIS Manager on the server, but as soon as we figure out what is causing that problem, I will enable fail request tracing. Thank you for the advice.